# How do I only show comment form to post author while comments is shown to everyone?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I think it's possible to query a wordpress post author id of the current post and compare it with the id of the current login user of the current page. Such that, if the IDs is a match, a comment form is shown, otherwise the comment form is hidden.

I did tried to do it. The IDs were retrieved and compared successfully, the criteria were met but, I'm not sure what is still keeping the comment form hidden.

I don't know if the argument to show or hide comments based on the above stated conditions is best to implement in my custom comment template review-comments.php or if it is best to implement the logic in my theme single review page template single-review.php where my custom comment template is included to show comments and comment form?

My trial was done in review-comment.php

```
<?php
if (have_comments()) :
    ?>
    <div class="escortreviewtext">
        <h4 class="rad3">Escort Reply:</h4>
        <div class="commentlistall">
            <?php wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'theme_comments', 'style' => 'div', 'type' => 'comment')); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="clear30"></div>

<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) :
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $post = get_post(); // Get the current post object
    $post_author_id = $post->post_author;

    if ($current_user->ID === $post_author_id || current_user_can('administrator')) :
        ?>
        <div class="commform" id="respond">
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-comments-post.php'); ?>" method="post" id="commentform">
                <div class="commtext col-100">
                    <?php _e('', 'escortwp'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="commtextarea" placeholder="Thanks dear❤️" tabindex="1" rows="10" style="width: 96%; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; margin-left: 10px; border: 1px solid #FE5ACB99;"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="clear10"></div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="pinkbutton commsubmitbutton rad25" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Reply', 'escortwp'); ?>" tabindex="2" />
                </div>

                <?php $replytoid = isset($_GET['replytocom']) ? (int)$_GET['replytocom'] : 0; ?>
                <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='<?php echo $replytoid; ?>' />
                <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" />
                <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
                <a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="#respond" class="cancel-comment-reply-link rad5" style="display: none;"><?php _e('Cancel reply', 'escortwp'); ?></a>
            </form>
        </div> <!-- COMMENTS FORM -->
    <?php endif;
endif; ?>

<!-- Display IDs at the footer for comparison -->
<footer>
    <p>Current User ID: <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?></p>
    <p>Post Author ID: <?php echo $post_author_id; ?></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Is the form in the browser source code? What's the result if you log `($current_user->ID === $post_author_id || current_user_can('administrator')) :`?

Comment: I wish I can show you screenshot but, that code line is perfect. The both IDs match perfect. Form is shown to admin but not to the page author even when the criteria is met.

Comment: Unfortunately dear, I'm in Africa and there no electricity now to power the computer for me to use chrome console. I just need to urgently correct the trouble. Kindly help me check. Thank you.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but it takes time, especially since I can't recreate the problem. You are logged in as the page author. The form is not in the browser source code? Are both if-statements returning true?

Comment: Yes, both IF statements are true.

Comment: Could CSS be hiding the form?

Comment: No dear. I've stripped css and it's still the same.

Comment: What does the html source code look like in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, PC is not on for me to check.

Comment: It works now. I decided to simplify the comparison and directly compares integer values. Then, viola!

Answer (score 0):

1. First the footer when only shown in the user login condition.
2. Debug the condition of `$current_user->ID === $post_author_id` and also check the data is retrieved from these variables. otherwise, the form is hidden.

   ```
   <?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
       <?php 
           $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
           $post = get_post(); // Get the current post object
           $post_author_id = $post->post_author;
       ?>
       <?php if ($current_user->ID === $post_author_id || current_user_can('administrator')): ?>
           <div class="commform" id="respond">
               <form action="<?php echo esc_url(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-comments-post.php'); ?>" method="post" id="commentform">
                   <div class="commtext col-100">
                       <?php _e('', 'escortwp'); ?>
                       <div class="clear"></div>
                       <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="commtextarea" placeholder="Thanks dear❤️" tabindex="1" rows="10" style="width: 96%; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; margin-left: 10px; border: 1px solid #FE5ACB99;"></textarea>
                   </div>

                   <div class="clear10"></div>
                   <div class="text-center">
                       <input type="submit" class="pinkbutton commsubmitbutton rad25" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Reply', 'escortwp'); ?>" tabindex="2" />
                   </div>

                   <?php $replytoid = isset($_GET['replytocom']) ? (int)$_GET['replytocom'] : 0; ?>
                   <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='<?php echo $replytoid; ?>' />
                   <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" />
                   <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
                   <a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="#respond" class="cancel-comment-reply-link rad5" style="display: none;"><?php _e('Cancel reply', 'escortwp'); ?></a>
               </form>
           </div> <!-- COMMENTS FORM -->
       <?php endif ?>
       <!-- Display IDs at the footer for comparison -->
       <footer>
           <p>Current User ID: <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?></p>
           <p>Post Author ID: <?php echo $post_author_id; ?></p>
       </footer>
   <?php endif ?>
   ```